# Ctrl/ Tab/ Shift + anything doesn't function as a hotkey (Shortcut Key) (Ubuntu 22.10)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm Using Ubuntu 22.10 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + anything doesn't function as a hotkey they only will write words Uppercase, for example if i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> instead of select all it will type "A" for me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> instead of Copy will type "C" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> will Write "V" and the list goes on. same goes for shift, tab doesn't even work when i press <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> nothing happens and super key doesn't work as well.

Here's a picture to my keyboard layout as well:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you already used something and tried to reassign the keys?

Comment: Hello David thanks for your comment, no, to be honest, I'm pretty new to Linux and Ubuntu so I don't know anything, although here's a picture of my keyboard layout I don't know if it helps. https://s28.picofile.com/file/8462086692/Screenshot_from_2023_04_12_16_13_36.png